# OpenXml. Look through existing footnotes and add new one

Tags: c#, openxml

I have OpenXML version 2.8.1.0. I need to open existing document, look through existing footnotes and then add the new footnote with the text at the exact place where docvariable is located. Please, help. I've tried several samples of how to find existing footnotes but seems they are not working with existing version of OpenXML. I tried the following code:

```
FootnotesPart footnotesPart = doc.MainDocumentPart.FootnotesPart;
if (footnotesPart != null)
{
    var footnotes = footnotesPart.Footnotes.Elements<Footnote>();
    var references = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<FootnoteReference>().ToArray();
    foreach (var footnote in footnotes)
...
}
```

I'm getting error on .ToArray() : "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.FootnoteReference>" don't have definition for "ToArray"

Comment: Try ToList() instead of ToArray();

Comment: ToList() is also not working.

Comment: Try removing the ".Document".  VS will automatically give you a list of properties when you type the period.  So I would reenter the line that is giving you issues and choose only properties that VS allows when you type the periods.

Comment: And I didn't know what to choose in the list. No property for FootnoteReference

Comment: Handle the same as Elements<Footnote>.  Footnote is a class and FotnoteReference should also be a class.

Comment: It does work at last this way, although I needed to itirate through all references to get the last one:
var references = mpart.Document.Body.Descendants<FootnoteReference>();
int MaxID = 0;
foreach (var refer in references)
{
 MaxID = (int)refer.Id;                                  
}

Comment: Try : var references = mpart.Document.Body.Descendants<FootnoteReference>().OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: It's not working this way... But I've solve the problem although it is elegant solution.